# Javascript variable seemingly won't set

Tags: javascript

In this simplified fiddle, I'm trying to re-set the value of "token" to be used in subsequent form submissions, but despite setting the value, the next pass through, 'token' is still set to the initial value of QWERTY.

```
var token = '';

function pollServer(token) {

    alert("Calling with token: " + token);

    alert("OLD: " + token);
    token = "ASDFG"; // new token
    alert("NEW: " + token);

}

function onsubmit_action() {

    alert("A: " + token);

    if (token === '') {
        // set the initial token
        token = 'QWERTY';
    }

    alert("B: " + token);
    pollServer(token);
    event.preventDefault();

}​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tUtRH/

The alerts should go:

```
<submit form>
A:
B: QWERTY
Calling with token: QWERTY
OLD: QWERTY
NEW: ASDFG

<submit form>

A: ASDFG
```

Instead, after the second form submission, I get:

```
A: QWERTY
```

Any slaps in the face or cold water dumped over my head would be really appreciated.  (Obviously this code has been stripped down to cover the bare minimum case, this is actually a bunch of polling/AJAX calls that gets/sets tokens and such.)

Comment: They're all such good answers, I wish I could choose them **all** correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the parameter to `pollServer` is called `token`.

What's happening is, inside `pollServer` you are setting the local `token`, not the global one.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is function scoped. By passing in a token paramater to the function `pollServer` you are creating a local variable called `token` which will be used instead of the global one.

This is one of the most commonly type of asked JS questions on SO. That and async variable timing assignment.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is a hard question to search for similar questions since it is hard to describe in a common way

Answer (score 2):

You have a global variable, `token`, that is masked by a function parameter `token`, so the assignment inside the function has no effect outside the function.

Comment: Yep, now I see, I've created a locally scoped variable of the same name as the global.  Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive variables in JavaScript are passed by value [1].  You should make any function (such as your pollServer()) function not only take an argument, but return the modified value, and make callers use the return value of the function.  More like:

```
function pollServer(token) {
   token = 'new value';
   return token;
}

function something_else() {
   var token = 'old value';
   token = pollServer(token);
   if (token != 'old value) {
       alert('Success!');
   }
}
```

[1] http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass/